# What version of Android should I develop for? (Now that M is out)

Tags: android

Title says it all really.

Does M really hold that many more notable features over L and K and will users adopt to it quickly? L only has a 9% adoption rate thus far (still trying to interpret what that means exactly)

Comment: it depends. on a lot of things.

Comment: The M Developer Preview is a developer preview. It will not be "out" for end users for a few months. The definition of "notable features" is personal, and Stack Overflow is not for seeking opinions. "still trying to interpret what that means exactly" -- ~5% of Android devices that access the Play Store are running Android 5.0 or 5.1.

Comment: Hi SleepsOnNewspapers. We don't really do opinion-based questions, and this is clearly an opinion-based question. Please have a look at The Tour (found under the help menu) to find out a bit more about what kind of questions we ask and answer here.

Comment: @DJClayworth the guy below answered the question in a manner that didn't really seem to be opinion based.

Comment: @CommonsWare now are these 5% accessing it daily or is that a measure over the past year? I'd think that of the people that access the play store every day, in a 1st world country, that it would be more than 5% no?

Comment: "now are these 5% accessing it daily or is that a measure over the past year?" -- [over the preceding month](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure developing for the latest version is such a good idea.

Unless you're developing a corporate application in which you know employees will get the needed OS, you'll want to reach the most users possible.

When I start a new project, I review [Android dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone) to find a balance between the newest version and the minimal users loss. Currently, developing for `4.0.3` or greater, grants you reaching 94% users, enjoying the features available since 4.x. As for me, it makes little sense starting developing on `5.x` (which grants you less than 10% users!), and then struggling and patching to get backwards compatibility for the large mass of users.